# How to find component folder in reactjs website project?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I am totally new to react js. Surfed react js learned structure. I have an web project but there is no component, render folder. But when i run the web project, it runs perfectly and i have inspected in browser source tab, it shows all folders like component, container, layout etc but it does not exist it in project folder. I have pulled project from google cloud repository.

here is the screenshot of folder and browser console source.

[image: Folder like component, container, layout exist in browser]

How to find all existing project folders?

Comment: The first image is bundle file, `npm run build` after they finish and build file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that you are showing, is a react build so it don't have source code.
You can find component in source code. If you have source code then go to your project and then scr directory and then components directory. You will get all components.

Comment: I dont have that. In cloud repository same thing is there. Should i ask source code instead of project build

Comment: yes sure do that because. Without source code you can do any changes. Build is only use for deployment.

Comment: But client they told to get source from Dawei. Whats mean by Dawei.

Comment: You can not get source form diawi because it a plateform to share you apk or ipa but not the source code. https://www.diawi.com/